# Outputting a max, min value and a group of decreasing & increasing numbers in a file

Tags: python, file, max, min, weather

```
f = open("file.txt","r")
s = len("file.txt")
for line in range(s):
    line = f.readline()
    a=line.split(",")[1]
    print(a)

f.close()
```

## it can only output the numbers and not from all the lines

I have 10 dates with a number next to them, separated by a comma (eg 27.10.207,25), which are in a file from top to bottom. I need to output the maximum & minimum number along with the a date next to it, and if there are 3 dates with increasing numbers, the first day of the increasing numbers will be outputted, along with the number of days with increasing number. Same goes for decreasing numbers.

Comment: Okay what's your question?

Comment: Please show the solutions you've tried rather than relying on SO as a free coding site.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'm trying to update and add code as time passes.

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses a nested `list-comprehension` and then the `builtin` `map()` `function` with the optional `key` parameter so that we `max` the `pairs` of `data` based on the second (`index 1`) value.

```
lines = open("file.txt","r").read().strip().split("\n")
pairs = [(a,int(b)) for a,b in [l.split(",") for l in lines]]
maxVal = max(pairs, key=lambda p: p[1])
minVal = min(pairs, key=lambda p: p[1])
```

which will give `maxVal` and `minVal` in the format:

```
(dateString, number)
```

This does the job in only a couple of `lines` for finding the `min` and `max` values, but doesn't handle the `increasing` and `decreasing` part.

If I attempt that part, I am bound to have had misinterpreted what you meant and it will be a waste of time for both of us. However, if you can update the question to explain that part in more depth, I will see what I can do tomorrow but for now, all that I could accomplish properly was the `min` and `max` part.